# New Password, please help!

Tags: password-recovery

I haven't used my linux computer in a couple of months because I went abroad, so I downgraded to be safe in case it got stolen; But the thing is I cannot log in because the password I believe to have used does not work any more.  Is there a way I can change this or do I have to take it into a store? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift when you bootup your computer.  The GRUB menu will come up.  Select "Advanced Options" and then "Recovery Mode."  Once you are in recovery mode, type:

`mount -o remount,rw /`

to get your filesystem mounted read/write.  Then type:

`passwd {your username}`

Then enter your new password.  Reboot and you should be good to go.  Let me know if you have any problems and we'll take it step by step.